# Web API Individual Accounts: how add Roles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

in ASP Web API i use the individual accounts to register the user. I have implemented this functionality following this official tutorial:

[Web API Individual Accounts](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Now i want be able to assign a Role to the user: when is executed the Register method i want pass also the role in the POST request:

```
{
   "UserName": "Alice",
   "Password": "password123",
   "ConfirmPassword": "password123",
   "Role": "admin"                  -> i want add this
}
```

and the Register method must value the database's table properly.
How can i handle the roles in the web api individual accounts? There's any tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in your code after you have created the user and the appropriate role

```
var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "RoleName");
```

You should also add the **Role** property to your view model (it is normally called **RegisterBindingModel**) which is passed to the **Register** method.

**Update**

Here's a complete example how a **Register** method could look like (**RoleEntity** and **UserEntity** are my implementations of the appropriate classes in Identity, but this will also work with your custom implementation)

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterAsync(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    var user = new UserEntity { UserName = model.UserName };
    var role = model.Role.ToString();

    if (await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
    {
        var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new RoleEntity(role));

        if (roleResult != IdentityResult.Success)
        {
            return roleResult;
        }
    }

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return result;
    }

    var addToRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, role);

    return !addToRoleResult.Succeeded ? addToRoleResult : IdentityResult.Success;
}
```

My **RegisterViewModel** looks something like this

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "User name", Prompt="Please enter user name...")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", Prompt="Please enter password...")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password", Prompt = "Please enter confirm password...")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public Roles Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is any guide or book where can i document on this argument?

Comment: The [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/identity) lacks a lot of information. Better resources are the blogs of [Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/category/asp-net-security/) and [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/all).

Comment: @Tom I have updated my post to give you a complete example how you can customize the **Register** method to support role adding. The **Role** property in the view model could also be a string.